# Combing data from multiple tables using view on mysql

Tags: mysql, view

I have two tables `Employee` and `Customer`.

I want an `Employee`'s Name and Address and then a `Customer`'s Name and Address in one view.

This is what I have:

```
CREATE VIEW Mail_List AS
SELECT C.CustName, C.CustAddress
FROM Customers C
UNION
Select E.EmpCustName, E.EmpCustAddress
From Employees E;
```

But it says `No rows were affected`. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`No rows were affected` is not an error that should appear for `SELECT` operations.

How are you calling the view? Try doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM Mail_List;
```

For clarity, you might rewrite the view as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Mail_List AS
SELECT C.CustName AS name, C.CustAddress AS address, 'customer' AS `type`
FROM Customers C
UNION ALL
SELECT E.EmpCustName AS name, E.EmpCustAddress AS address, 'employee' AS `type`
From Employees E
ORDER BY name;
```